# el is not populated correctly in short example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

According to backbonejs.org

All views have the `el` property at all times.  Also, to link a view to an already existing element id, you should pass it in when instantiating the view.

In this small example below, I pass in the already existing id in as a string.  When I log it to the console later it is logged incorrectly as an empty div.  Was I suppose to pass in the actual element and not a string that specified the element id?

Either, way I find it strange that logging the id, logs an actual empty div with that id.

```
/***************************************************************************************************
*/

    var ModelMediaPane = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            visible:          false,
        }
    });
    var model_media_pane = new ModelMediaPane();

    var ViewMediaPane = Backbone.View.extend({
    });
    var view_media_pane = new ViewMediaPane({
      model: model_media_pane,
      id: 'mi_holder'
    });


    console.log(model_media_pane.get('visible'));
    console.log(view_media_pane.id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass an existing `id` like that, you do it like this:

```
var view_media_pane = new ViewMediaPane({
  model: model_media_pane,
  el: '#mi_holder'
});
```

Otherwise you're just setting the `id` to the created element.

Comment: per the docs, you should not do that when you are specifying the `id` of the element. Notice, I'm not using the `id` property, I'm using the `el` property.

Comment: my bad, i misread, at the same time that is a string, it would make more sense to put it in the id property which actually holds a string,  and not the el property, a weird API

Comment: In this instance, it's a selector, which is a special kind of string. During initialization, the [`_ensureElement`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-140) method gets called, which uses [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement). You could alternatively set `el` to `document.getElementById("mi_holder")` or any equivalent of that.